# How to Use vue-dropzone to upload images with axios?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, vuejs2, axios, dropzone

I'm trying to use vue-dropzone to upload my images to the database, the uploading API example provided by the backend developer is like this:

```js
export const actions = {
  uploadGallery (ctx, file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.$axios.$post('galleries/upload', file)
        .then(resolve)
        .catch(reject)
    })
  }
}
```

My dropzone options is like this:

```js
  dropzoneOptions: {
    url: 'galleries/upload',
    thumbnailWidth: 175,
    thumbnailHeight: 150,
    maxFilesize: 1,
    addRemoveLinks: true
  }
```

I just simply put the request URL in the dropzone options, but it doesn't work correctly.
Can anybody show me how I can integrate the dropzone and Axios? (also keep the progress bar function, I can set `autoProcessQueue` to `false` and use an external method to upload images, but if I do that, the progress bar won't update)

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

What I did in the end is stopping the auto-uploading process by option: "autoProcessQueue:false", and then retrieve the images from dropzone using its provided api and upload the image manually using Axios.

Comment: Hi, are you able to provide code example for this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @HNG Sorry, I have left the company and I don't have the code anymore.